# Audacity and SoundTap won't recognise any recording devices?

Tags: windows, windows-8, recording, audio-recording, audacity

Audacity and SoundTap won't recognise any of my recording devices?

[image: audacity recording error]

[image: soundtap won't recognise the mic]

However under Recording Devices, both my microphone drivers are recognised as making sound.

[image: recording devices making sound]

Please help.

Comment: Did you check the project sample rate?

Comment: Changing the sample rate from CD quality to DVD quality made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen shot you provide has the answer. It's the sample rate. I suspect you're trying to record at a rate which isn't supported by your card. See if you can reduce the rate.

> Sample rate is the number of samples of audio carried per second, measured in Hz or kHz (one kHz being 1 000 Hz). For example, 44 100 samples per second can be expressed as either 44 100 Hz, or 44.1 kHz. Bandwidth is the difference between the highest and lowest frequencies carried in an audio stream

[Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn8cf2kJjOAhUMaD4KHVdXB-sQFggfMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.audacityteam.org%2Fwiki%2FSample_Rates&usg=AFQjCNFq8U8TYs87MMRXKfiR0AG30TpT0Q&bvm=bv.128617741,d.dmo)